# drop lmdb database using python

Tags: python, lmdb

I would like to drop an lmdb database.  The following hits 'typerror:invalid type' on the txn.drop(db_name) line.

```
import lmdb 
def kill_db(db_name):
    print('ABOUT TO DELETE DB '+str(db_name)+'!!!!')
    raw_input('press enter to continue or ctrl-C to not')
    env = lmdb.open(db_name, readonly=False)
    txn = lmdb.Transaction(env)
    txn.drop(db_name)
```

any clues as to why this is happening? 
I am new to lmdb (as you may have guessed) so be gentle.

Comment: What is the rest of the TypeError? It should say what it expected and what it received.

Comment: ABOUT TO DELETE DB testdb.test!!!!
    press enter to continue or ctrl-C to not
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "lmdb_utils.py", line 215, in <module>
    kill_db('testdb.test')
    File "lmdb_utils.py", line 198, in kill_db
    txn.drop(db_name,delete=True)
    TypeError: invalid type

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps you:

```
import lmdb 
def kill_db(db_name):
    print('ABOUT TO DELETE DB '+str(db_name)+'!!!!')
    raw_input('press enter to continue or ctrl-C to not')
    in_db = lmdb.open(db_name)
    with in_db.begin(write=True) as in_txn:
        db = in_db.open_db()
        in_txn.drop(db)
        print in_txn.stat()
```

You can find a documentation here:
https://lmdb.readthedocs.org/en/release/

Another way, if you want to completely remove the LMDB from your disk, you could also just use:

```
import os
import shutil
if os.path.exists(db_name):
    shutil.rmtree(db_name)
```

Comment: thanks, i hadnt noticed the db just inhabits a local directory. I didnt try the in_txn.drop yet